# language locales configuration file

Tags: locale

Ubuntu, where is the Locales configuration file.  I want to leave `en_us_utf8` and remove others like `en_GB or en_zimbabwe`.  Is it the locale-archive file `/usr/lib/locale`, because I can't open this file.

Comment: whats on your engine desktop, server, something custom?

Comment: What file are you trying to open? What is the output of writing `locale` in your terminal?

Answer (score 1):

If you like to remove dispensable language packs from your installation just enter:

```
sudo apt-get install localepurge
```

Now you see a debconf interface that asks you to select all languages like to keep.

This may take a while but is the easiest solution for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

You can reconfigure your language with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`, then answer the questions and let it regenerate the language cache.

On a side note: you shouldn't be tampering with languages manually, they're waaay too easy to break.